# Add custom markup to txt files in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to add some keywords that are highlighted (for example [FAIL] in red and [PASS] in green) into Notepad++. How would I do that for a .txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a [User Defined Language](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/languages/user-defined-languages) or modify one of the existing ones.

There is a UI inside of Notepad++ for defining the keywords and markup (it's a bit involved). You can access it from `Language -> Define your language...`

[image: define language]